# automatically build a org chart based on self-referencing sql employee table?

Tags: sql-server, automation, ms-office

sol have a standard self referencing employee table in sql 2005 and thought it would be cool to have an automated way to be able to build an org. chart like this

[image: link text]
<sub>(source: [freeorgchart.com](https://www.freeorgchart.com/interfaces/orgchart_800.jpg))</sub>

i want somethign that can be scheduled to run daily because my company has a large team and things change frequently. as an aside, i am re-fleshing the employee table (1000) records daily from Active Directory.)

anyone know a simple way to do this?
visio/ vba?
excel/ vba?
winforms/ c#?

Answer (score 0):

Visio allows you to generate an org chart from a SQL database, but I'm not sure you can automate it (may have to have Visio installed on the server if you can) and it's a fair amount of work to set up the template file to lay everything out the way you like.  So the short answer is "probably possible in Visio, but definitely a pain for non-Visio gurus"